# AWS Glue match for a partition column containing null as on the partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, partitioning

I am using aws-cli to query from AWS Glue for a table containing partition columns. One of the partition columns has the name `date` and one of the partition column values is `null`. I want to query it.

I get an error if I query as shown in the following attempts:

```
aws glue get-partitions --database-name <DB> --table-name <TABLE>  --expression="date=null"
An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the GetPartitions operation: Unsupported expression 'NULL'

aws glue get-partitions --database-name <DB> --table-name <TABLE>  --expression="date='null'"
An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the GetPartitions operation: com.amazonaws.daylight.core.exceptions.InvalidPartitionValueException: null is not a date.

aws glue get-partitions --database-name <DB> --table-name <TABLE>  --expression="date=\'null\'"
An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the GetPartitions operation: Lexical error at line 1, column 6.  Encountered: "\\" (92), after : ""
```

If I query:

```
aws glue get-partitions --database-name <DB> --table-name <TABLE>  --expression="date is null"
{
    "Partitions": []
}
```

then I don't get any value, which is wrong as well. I've verified that there is an object under that partition.

This is the table from AWS Glue interface

[image]